# How to apply wire texture for realistic rendering of embroidery?

Tags: opengl, rendering, texture, 2d-graphics, three.js

I am building an algorithm which takes a bitmap image as input and render the image as an embroidery design.

The different steps are :

- Vectorize the image, I keep only 5 colors  (Done)
- Generate
  stitches lines (Done)
- Apply wire embroidery texture to the lines,
  add lights and show a realistic rendering ( It's this step that I am
  having trouble with)

Let's take an example.
The original image is :

[image: Original image]

From there, I vectorize the image and obtain an SVG file.

After that, I generate stitches lines automatically which you can find here (svg file): https://www.dropbox.com/s/jmi6rz1ixgkjjpb/flowers_fill_0.7_vLongShort_space_randomLength.svg?dl=0

When you zoom in, it looks like this :

[image: stitches]

If I export the svg as png, I get :

[image: ExportPng]

As you can see; having this result is not enough to render realistically the embroidery design.

I am looking to have a texture more like this :

[image: Real]

I tried generating a normal map and the use it adds some depth, but again, the result looks very plastic ... :

[image: Rendering with normal map]

I don't know what I should do now to have a realistic rendering ...
At first, it wasn't supposed to be a computer graphic problem so I am not a specialist in the area, but I think using webgl or opengl is the best choice.

However, I don't know how to give the rights textures to the lines ...

Answer (score 2):

Picking up from step 2, where you generated line segments to represent individual stitches, I would first suggest that you apply rounded ends to each segment, rather than square ends.

I would then convert each segment to an **outline**, (i.e. each rounded stitch becomes an separate poly-line representing the outer boundary.)

For example, suppose you start with point A & point B, representing a single stitch in line segment form. We can derive the rounded outline of this segment with the following Javascript code using **THREE.js**:

```
    function outlineSegment (Ax, Ay, Bx, By, radius){
        var radius = radius || 0.5; //millimeters?
        var A = new THREE.Vector2(Ax, Ay);
        var B = new THREE.Vector2(Bx, By);
        var C = B.clone().sub(A).normalize().multiplyScalar(radius);
        var angle = C.angle();
        var outline = new THREE.Shape();
        outline.moveTo( B.x + C.y, B.y - C.x );
        outline.absarc(B.x, B.y, radius, angle-Math.PI/2, angle+Math.PI/2);
        outline.lineTo(A.x - C.y, A.y + C.x);
        outline.absarc(A.x, A.y, radius, angle+Math.PI/2, angle+Math.PI*3/2);
        outline.autoClose = true;
        return new THREE.ShapeGeometry(outline);
    }
```

The above function finishes by **triangulating** the polyline into faces, (See the orange area in the included picture.)

Next, send these faces to be rendered by the **GPU**, applying a **vertex shader** which sets a ***vec2*** varying variable (sounds redundant, but it's not) indicating the vertex position relative to the original line segment (which we have included as *vertex attributes*)

Now, we move on to the **fragment shader**, where we use the varying variable created in the vertex shader to derive a **normal**.

Let's say that "linePos" is the position along the line segment, (i.e. the x-value, if the line is horizontal. y-value if it is vertical, etc.)

Furthermore, let's say "lineDist" is the distance from the central line segment, e.g. -2 if it's 2 units to the left of the line (purple arrows) or +5 if it's on the right (blue arrows).

We can use these two values, derived from the varying variable, to create a normal for the point on the thread.

A bit of this code might be:

```
abs(sin(linePos+lineDist))
```

but there's a fair bit more than that to write.
I can't go through and write the entire program for you here & now, but hopefully these ideas & diagram will shine some light in the right direction.

Best of luck.

[image: embroidery geometry diagram]